# PHP/Laravel/Bootsrap fetch data

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4

I've got an tiny little problem. I've got a table in database called 'player_skills'. It contains columns like this (example):

player_id | skill_id | value | count

15             0        10      12

15            1         10       51

...

15           8         10        12

The player_id is actually an id of the player which is column 'id' under 'players' table.
Also there are eight skills. Value is the default value (which is irrelevant in this case). The count is the value (the value of the players skill).

Basically, what I want is to pull data into a Bootstrap tabs (example):

```
        <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="?skill0" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="?skill1" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="?skill2" data-toggle="tab">Section 3</a></li>
...
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="?skill0">
    <p>I'm in Section A.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="?skill1">
    <p>Howdy, I'm in Section B.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="?skill2">
    <p>What up girl, this is Section C.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I want to order it (from the highest to the lowest,( also I have an 'group_id' column in every player, so I don't want it to include a player which has an group_id equals to three) but for every skill). Also I have one skill that's located in the 'players' table (column called 'experience') and I've done it like this:

```
    public function highscores()
{
    $players = Player::orderBy('experience','desc')->get();
    return View::make('aac.highscores')->with('players', $players);
}
```

It works just fine, but I need it in tabs to change for every skill.

Comment: Can we have more informations about what you want to print exactly ? A list of players with skills tabs for each one or a list skills tabs with players inside ? A small draw or schema could be helpful.

Comment: @Alexandre Butynski
A list skills tabs with players inside. Basically to fetch the player name via player_id, and the skill_id, and order them from the highest to the lowest. Then when you change tab, you'll get another skill that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your need is really well covered by Laravel. First, you have to declare a many to many relationship between skills and players like this (read more : http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many) :

```php
class Skill extends Eloquent {

    public function players() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Player', 'player_skills', 'skill_id', 'player_id')
                    ->withPivot('value', 'count');
    }

}
```

Then you can get all your skills from your database with the players linked with the `with` method. This method is not obligatory (you can use `all` instead) but eager loading is a good practice here (read more : http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading) :

```
class SkillController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        $skills = Skill::with('players')->get();

        return View::make('skill.index', array('skills' => $skills));
    }

}
```

Finally just can iterate over your skills array and over the players arrays inside each skill (read more about blade templating : http://laravel.com/docs/templates#blade-templating) :

```
<!-- index.blade.php -->
<div class="tabbable tabs-left">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    @foreach ($skills as $skill)
        <li><a href="?{{ $skill->id }}" data-toggle="tab">{{ $skill->name }}</a></li>       
    @endforeach
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
    @foreach ($skills as $skill)
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="?{{ $skill->id }}">
            @foreach ($skills->players as $player)
                <p>{{ $player->name }} : {{ $player->pivot->count }} points !</p>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to order your players by skill count you can use the `sortBy` function like that (read more : http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#collections) :

```
$orderedPlayers = $skill->players->sortBy(function($player) {
    return $player->pivot->count;
});
```

Ask if something is not clear.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. Second, I get an error: `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'thefs.skills' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `skills`) (Bindings: array ( ))`. Actually it's player_skils table, but I don't know what to change haha.

Comment: If one of your model don't follow the convention, you have to set the table name in the model with `protected $table = 'skill';`. The relation table is set in the relationship declaration as I explained. When do you get this error ?

Comment: When I try to enter the view. I also have a new error(it's a long one): http://paste.laravel.com/FUQ , I know it's something with the tables, here's how my tables look like: http://2.imgland.net/NECS_h.png

Comment: Hey, can you spend 5 seconds searching by yourself before to ask question ? The error is clear : `Unknown column 'player_skills.skill_id'` because, in your table, the column is named `skillid` instead of `skill_id`.

Comment: Hah, sorry, didn't see that. I'm getting an Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$players error now. The error is on this line: `<?php foreach ($skills->players as $player): ?>`.

Comment: Have you define the players() function in the Skill model as I describe ?

Comment: I haven't defined the relationships, loool. I'm really bad in relationships and polymorphism, should I do many to many relationships? getting confused right now..

Comment: Yes. As I explained before, there is a many to many relatinship between players and skills (a player has many skills and a skill has many players). To declare the relationship, just use the code I have shown you before. If you have trouble with basic concepts read the Laravel doc.