# Laravel 4 relationships

Tags: many-to-many, laravel, laravel-4

I can't find a way to define relationships. Here is my previous question, you can review it to find what I'm looking for: [PHP/Laravel/Bootsrap fetch data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982455/php-laravel-bootsrap-fetch-data)

I've defined the relationship for skills like this:

```
public function skills()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Skill', 'player_skills', 'skillid', 'player_id');
}
```

Still getting the U`ndefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$players` error pointing at `$skills->players as $player`.

Comment: Can you post the code for which you are getting error? the code you have posted has nothing to do with the error

Comment: @TryingTobemyself http://paste.laravel.com/JoD

Comment: from where are you getting `$skills`? model code??

Comment: http://paste.laravel.com/JoG  assuming you have your relationships setup correctly.  In your model, you also need to be pulling pivot vairables.  Please add your models into the paste bucket as well and I'll be able to answer you fully.

Comment: @TryingTobemyself http://paste.laravel.com/JpD

Comment: The relationships don't make any sense.  I am assuming that a player can have many skills.  Can one skill have many players associated with it?

Comment: @user1669496 I don't think so. That's why I am asking you. Could you clarify it a bit? I'm really confused with all of this. I just wan't it to display the skills.

Comment: Okay, please see my answer below.  This is assuming a player can have lots of skills.  And lots of players can have the same skill.  In other words, a skill can have many players and a player can have many skills (many-to-many).  The last paste should get you pretty close to where you need to be.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, with the `hasMany` function, you are setting up a one-to-many relationship, but it looks like you are sending it the name of a pivot table as a parameter, which would only be required for a many-to-many.

I'm going to assume you actually want a many to many relationship and your keys are correct (they are in the question you linked, but `skillid` is different here, so let's go with `skill_id`)

Also, the way you are looping through the data is wrong. `$players->skills` doesn't make any sense because `$players` doesn't have `skills`, but `$player` does.

Here is what I have so far... http://paste.laravel.com/Jp8

With the newest information you have given, I think there might be some confusion about how a many-to-many relationship works in Laravel.  Please check this out when you get a chance, it should be pretty close to what you are looking for... http://paste.laravel.com/JqV

Comment: I'm getting an error: http://paste.laravel.com/Jrh
'players' is a seperate table, 'player_skills' is a seperate table.

Comment: I think the problem is you need an additional table for setting up the pivot.  I modified the paste to do some additional explaining and modified some of the parameters to match exactly what you have.  Hopefully it helps... http://paste.laravel.com/JrP